# Can you do calculations in the get/set ? c#

Tags: c#, calculation

Answered, thanks - plz note it was required for a project - I know it was not best practice

Can you do a calculation in the set clause? and it then returns the total when implemented?`

```
    public decimal TotalCost
     { 
      set
      { this.costTotal = (decimal)prodCost + (decimal)shipping + (decimal)insurance)}
       get
      { return this.costTotal}
     }
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Keep in mind that the `costTotal` is only calculated when you use the setter. But why do you use a setter for such a property when you don't use the `value` variable inside the setter? That doesn't make sense. Maybe you are looking for a getter-only property, which calculates the value on-the-fly.

Comment: `public decimal TotalCost => (decimal)prodCost + (decimal)shipping + (decimal)insurance);` (and no setter).

Answer (score 3):

> Can you do a calculation in the set clause?

Absolutely. However, in your specific case, it is not clear why would you do that. The point of a setter is to allow users of a class to safely manipulate fields of its objects. This is done using the `value` keyword. Since you are only interested in calculating a value using existing data, there is no reason to even use a setter. it seems more suitable to do the calculation in a getter only property:

```
public decimal TotalCost
{ 
    get
    {
        return (decimal)prodCost + (decimal)shipping + (decimal)insurance);
    }
}
```

A shorter version of the above code:

```
public decimal TotalCost => (decimal)prodCost + (decimal)shipping + (decimal)insurance;
```

Answer (score 0):

What others said, but maybe you're looking for a method:

```
public decimal CostTotal { get; private set; }

(...)

public void SetTotalCost(decimal prodCost, decimal shipping, decimal insurance)
{
   this.CostTotal = prodCost + shipping + insurance);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I suggest the below code for reading and writing your property.

```
private decimal totalCost;
public decimal TotalCost
     { 
       get { return totalCost = (decimal)prodCost + (decimal)shipping + (decimal)insurance);}
       set { totalCost = value;}
     }
```

Comment: This is a very bad suggestion, as setting TotalCost has no effect at all, and when TotalCost is read back it will show a completely different number to that which was used in the set

Comment: Using a setter that is ignored would confuse any user of this property

Comment: @LordWilmore  Please have a look at here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties

Comment: @TimO. What you want are three properties, one for ProdCost, one for Shipping, and one for Insurance, each of which are get and settable.  Then you need one property for TotalCost that is Get-only.  Your current example makes no sense

Comment: @LordWilmore in case the calculated value is used in another class or in a data transfer object then "set" may also be required. This is what I do. However, this may not be within the best practice.